Where do I find the STORAGE_GCS_DRIVER: gcs in Google Cloud Storage for Directus
I deployed Directus with Docker to GCP.
Where do I find the STORAGE_GCS_DRIVER: gcs in Google Cloud Storage for Directus.
What should I put as environnement variables ?
STORAGE_LOCATIONS: gcs
STORAGE_GCS_DRIVER: gcs
STORAGE_GCS_BUCKET: YOUR_CLOUD_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME
STORAGE_GCS_CREDENTIALS: YOUR_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_KEY_JSON

npm i @directus/drive-gcs

Sharing this as a community wiki for the benefit of others
As mentioned by @John Hanley

npm i @directus/drive-gcs

